# How to use JBuddy SDK to create a simple yahoo messenger client?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, api, instantmessenger

I tried to find a free .NET API which I could use for making a messenger client and after searching I found it can be done using JBuddy SDK.

[Instant Messaging SDK : The JBuddy SDK](http://www.zion.com/products/jbuddy/sdk/)

From what the site says, they made a wrapper for .NET of their Java API for yahoo messenger called JBuddy.dll

I downloaded the JBuddy Developer Tools and got a JBuddy.jar instead of a *.dll as expected.

How can i obtain JBuddy.dll and use it to make a very simple yahoo messenger client?

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered from their help files. You execute the .jar file. Install the dev tools and you can select .NET tools in the installer list. More information can be found here [Getting Started PDF](http://www.zion.com/support/jbuddy/sdk/docs/GettingStartedGuide.pdf)

Edit: 
After installing it myself I found the Jbuddy.dll file in 'Drive letter:\JBuddy\JBuddySDK\lib'
and samples in C# can be found in 'JBuddy\JBuddySDK\demos\C#'. Hope it helped!

Comment: *embarrassed* :) I actually extracted the .jar and was searching for a .dll inside :)

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on the download link and got this file: JBuddyDeveloperTools-6.3.110808.jar.

I double clicked on this and it installed the developer tools, complete with the dll.